# Cmake won't create .so version and soversion symlinks

Tags: cmake

What are all the necessary conditions for cmake to create and install shared objects with a proper soname version and relevant symlinks?

I have recently upgraded my system, and what used to work with cmake 2.8, doesn't work anymore with cmake 3.7. I've checked the latest documentation but I can't make sense of it, with regard to my problem.

I used to have .so files installed, with the real .so file with the full version, in addition to symlinks.

```
 pluginname.so.1 => pluginname.so.1.1.0
 pluginname.so.1.1.0
```

**Now, cmake only builds and installs**  pluginname.so **without any version suffix nor symlinks.**

I don't use NO_SONAME anywhere:
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_tgt/NO_SONAME.html#prop_tgt:NO_SONAME

```
add_library(${PLUGIN_NAME} MODULE ${SRC})

# I call message(...) to check that the values are indeed set:
message("plugin ${PLUGIN_NAME}") 
message("version ${CORE_MAJOR_VERSION}.${PLUGIN_MAJOR_VERSION}.${PLUGIN_BUGFIX_VERSION}") 
message("soversion: ${CORE_MAJOR_VERSION}")
message("prefix ${PLUGIN_PREFIX}") 

if (NOT NO_SONAME)
   message("Ok, no_soname is not set!")
endif()

set_target_properties(${PLUGIN_NAME} PROPERTIES
    VERSION ${CORE_MAJOR_VERSION}.${PLUGIN_MAJOR_VERSION}.${PLUGIN_BUGFIX_VERSION}
    SOVERSION ${CORE_MAJOR_VERSION} 
    PREFIX ${PLUGIN_PREFIX}
)
 install(TARGETS ${PLUGIN_NAME} DESTINATION ${PLUGIN_INSTALL_DIR})
```

What other debugging strategies would work here?

I have tried changing the *add_library(${PLUGIN_NAME} MODULE ${SRC})* line replacing *MODULE* with *SHARED* but it does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: After I answered I just re-read your question and saw that you say you tried with `SHARED`... and when you tried I believe you deleted the build directory and started a fresh new configuration for cmake...: `rm -rf build && mkdir build && cd build && cmake ..` , right?

Comment: One thing you could do is to check the build dir, if those are created there. Plus: what OS are you working on?

Comment: It works.  Thanks. I'm using gentoo. I'm sure I did rm -rf  in the build dir, cmake .. etc, AND I did try SHARED but apparently I didn't do both at the same time. I tried again and it works. Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad it worked! Maybe I will add it at some point in time (undefined) the "cleaning" up part to the answer as a note or something....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are adding a "MODULE" library and not a "SHARED" one.

I think this might be related to the following:
https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/commit/f799ffb5cb895855ac2aba54765622b81db5be38

and here is stressed again:
https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/raw/f799ffb5cb895855ac2aba54765622b81db5be38/Help/release/dev/modules-no-soname.rst

> - The `SONAME` field is no longer set for `MODULE` libraries   created with the :command:`add_library` command.  `MODULE`
>     libraries are meant for explicit dynamic loading at runtime.   They
>     cannot be linked so `SONAME` is not useful.

Before you could have set `SONAME` and have `VERSION` and `SOVERSION` set also for `MODULE` libraries.
That's the only thing I can think of is preventing you to set the `VERSION` and `SOVERSION` for your library.

More references:
https://gitlab.cern.ch/dss/eos/commit/18ff0746ff4bc1263648fe3fdda79075ce262093
https://gitlab.cern.ch/dss/eos/commit/a7a6d486168e4de9a25eddd84cb19af0bab1ab5f

---

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: When you switch between `MODULE` to `SHARED` configuration or viceversa, it's a good practice to remove the "old" CMake configuration files.
If your build is out-of-source (which I suggest) and the directory is called build, then from the root directory of your project, after you've changed the desired configuration in the `CMakeLists.txt`, you will do something like:

```
rm -rf build && mkdir build && cd build && cmake ..
```

This will assure you that you start from a clean configuration state before building the project.