# How to Prevent CMake from Generating Library Symlinks when Using VERSION and SOVERSION

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries

I have a build system which uses CMake to generate a primary daemon and a handfull of shared libraries which are dynamically loaded based on configuration at runtime (via `dlopen`).  Now, however, I need to support another build environment based on Windows+exfat which doesn't support symlinks (`CMake Error: failed to create symbolic link 'libfoo.so.1': Operation not permitted`).  I cannot change this build requirement as it is coming from another part of the company.  Adding a post-install cleanup step to remove the aberrant symlinks won't work as the build fails the moment the symlink is generated.

In my research, I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61788533/how-can-i-prevent-cmake-from-creating-a-symlink-for-shared-libraries-on-build-n) SO post which describes exactly what I want using `NAMELINK_SKIP`.  Unfortunately, it seems to indicate that setting either of `VERSION` or `SOVERSION` breaks this functionality.  This project does use both of these variables as we use shared library revisioning to keep track of changes to the libraries independently (each library basically provides vendor-generated configuration blob necessary to initialize a specific hardware topology).  Library revisioning is an important property for us to preserve.

So, in short, How can I get CMake to not generate symlinks for my shared library in the first place yet still retain fully versioned libraries?

Comment: "How can I get CMake to not generate symlinks for my shared library in the first place yet still retain fully versioned libraries?" - Am I correctly understand that your want CMake to create for a library **only** `libfoo.so.1.2` file, and your `dlopen` call loads the library using exactly that name?

Comment: Precisely.  The symlinks are never used; I just never had a need to remove them before this.

Comment: If you just want different library names for different versions, you could simply adjust name of the library (e.g. via [OUTPUT_NAME](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/OUTPUT_NAME.html) property). SOVERSION mechanism is fully about using the **version-independent** name of the library for **link** with, but **runtime** will use **version-specific** file.

Comment: Hm, fair point.  Though, if memory serves, isn't the sorev also stored somewhere in the ELF header?  I suppose I could set it after the fact via elfutils or similar though that seems a bit extreme just to disable some symlinks.  Ideally I would like to preserve all versioning such that I could "statically" link against this shared library (such that the application won't start without the correct sorev) for other applications but this is, admittedly, more of a secondary concern.

Comment: "isn't the sorev also stored somewhere in the ELF header?" - It is stored in the ELF, but as far as I know, it isn't used by the runtime loader. "such that the application won't start without the correct sorev" - The application may find the library using only its exact name (e.g. `libfoo.so.1.2`). I see a little reason to check that name **again**, against the library soversion. BTW, the proper type of library to be loadeded via `dlopen` is MODULE, not a SHARED. Symlinks and soversions are not created for MODULE libraries: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42183903.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't heard of MODULE before.  That, with the addition of a rename at the end, seems to do what I want.  If you want to write this up as an answer I would gladly accept it.

Comment: I wonder if this is considered a CMake defect? Considering that the docs I quote in my answer in the Q&A you linked says "_When building or installing appropriate symlinks are created **if the platform supports symlinks** and the linker supports so-names_". If anyone ends up raising an issue ticket, ping me with a link to it.

Comment: @starball: Your quote of the docs is started with "For **shared** libraries ..". So it is applicable only to the SHARED libraries, not to the MODULE ones:) Seriosly, MODULE libraries are used much less than SHARED ones. So it is understandable that CMake documentation doesn't explicitly mention them as an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the library is used only with `dlopen` mechanism, then the proper type for it is MODULE, not a SHARED:

```
add_library(foo MODULE <sources>)
```

For such libraries, CMake do not append SOVERSION to the filename and do not create symlinks. (The whole purpose of SONAME mechanism is to **link** with **version-independent** filename and to use **version-dependent** file at **runtime**. Since MODULE libraries are not linked with (at build time), they don't benefit from that mechanism).

---

If you want the name of the library file to contain a version string, then you could set OUTPUT_NAME of the library:

```
add_library(foo MODULE <sources>)
# This will make the output file to be named as "libfoo.1.2.so",
# exactly that name should be used in 'dlopen' calls.
set_target_properties(foo PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME foo.1.2)
```